# Create Self-Referencing Hierarchical Table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Background**

I have a class that looks more or less like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    [Id]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public bool MyBoolean { get; set; } 
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass ChildOne { get; set; }
    public MyClass ChildTwo { get; set; }
}
```

I will need to use a stored procedure to load a set of records, but that's ok as long as the structure itself is correct.

For any instance of `MyClass`, one or both of the children can be null. Any instance of `MyClass` can be used in a parent class - but the child itself doesn't need to know about this relationship, and a child can be used by *any number* of parents.

**Problem**

With this structure, I get the following error when creating a new migration:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'MyClass' and 'MyClass'. The principal end of this association
>   must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API
>   or data annotations.

This error makes sense - when given a structure of an object with a foreign key to itself, I am not surprised that EF has a hard time determining the principal end. I'm not sure how to fix this, though.

I've tried some different Fluent mappings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().HasOptional(x => x.ChildOne).WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.ChildOne);
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().HasOptional(x => x.ChildOne).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.ChildOne);
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().HasOptional(x => x.ChildOne);
```

(Note: I didn't try these concurrently - I did one at a time & duplicated it for ChildTwo.)

I *was* able to get a migration to work by adding a `ChildThree` property to MyClass, but that doesn't make sense and isn't a useful property; it just creates another foreign key on the table but this isn't needed in my model.

So, in summary:

1. How do I get this structure to work the way I want? I think the secret is in some Fluent mapping voodoo but I'm very unfamiliar with that library and I don't know how to get that to work.
2. Why does adding a *third* (unneeded, unwanted) property fix everything and allow the migration to scaffold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fluent mapping is totally wrong.

You should do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().HasOptional(p => p.ChildOne).WithOptionalDependent();
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().HasOptional(p => p.ChildTwo).WithOptionalDependent();
```